# Passing string into Onchange

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time passing a string constant into an onchange event. 
code example which i am trying:

```
var rvalue = "hi";
var r1 = '<label style="vertical-align:2px;">Group by: </label>' +
    '<select id="pwx_documents_range_groupby" onchange="ravi('+rvalue+');">' +
    '<option value="listview" selected="selected">List View</option><option value="notetype">Note Type</option><option value="author">Author View</option>'+
    '<option value="cat">Cat</option></select>'
```

This is just sample code.. But the question is once drop down change it will call ravi function and throw me the error 'hi' is undefined. If i am passing 0 instead of hi it works great. I am totally surprise why it will not accept the string.

Anybody have any idea that would be great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either set `rvalue = "'hi'"` or quote it in the body: `'onchange="ravi(\''+rvalue+'\');">'`

Comment: Thanks.Now it throw me syntax error. i am using that u gave me onchange="ravi(\"'+rvalue+'\");

Comment: @ravi Had a small bug in that version, you need to escape single quotes inside the double quotes! Updated answer to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

That is because rvalue is a string. You need to wrap strings with quotes. So it should be something like - `onchange="ravi(\''+rvalue+'\');">'`